# No need for state in React components if using Redux and React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Managing state with React only**

I understand that if you're creating an application using React only, you will end up managing all of your state within different React components you create.

**Managing state with React and Redux**

If you decide to use Redux in combination with React, you can then move all of the state from each of your React components into the overall Redux application state. Each component that requires a slice of the Redux application state can then hook into the state via React-Redux's `connect` function.

**Question**

Does this mean that you no longer need to write any React components that deal with React's `state` (i.e. `this.setState`) since React-Redux is `connect`ing the React components with Redux state by passing data into the `container` component as `props`?

Comment: Yes. Whether you should or not requires more discussion and specifics about your app. It's always nice to have a single source of truth though.

Comment: Still when you want to stick to React only, but are searching for a more lightweight approach to handle component state, you could add a state management library like MobX (https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/). It can help you with the internal component state (https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.5xoga86e9) but also store the state outside of your component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different opinions on this, but the general view seems to be that redux should only contain "application state". Individual react components like dropdowns or modals will still have their own state.

There is still a lot of debate on this though, check out this issue for example about how to manage local component state: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/159

Some projects have been popping up that are trying to solve this "problem":

- [redux-react-local](https://github.com/threepointone/redux-react-local)
- [recompose withReducer](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withreducer) (more for reducer semantics for local, not global state)

Comment: I second this. Let's hear what Redux' creator says :) https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/623097205386293248

Comment: I agree as well: state can be useful e.g. for an input component, where user can edit an input field, only updating state in small cycles. When the state change (content of input field) can be contained to the small react component, without the need for the rest of the world to know. Where the need to go full-cycle to Redux (possibly triggering many other methods) is only needed if user presses enter etc.

Comment: I agree, Redux is a tool to gather global state into a store and should be used as such only when the state needs to be connected.